# How to retrieve first H1 from an Url?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am preparing for interview questions from a site , and couldn't think of solution for following, can some body help?

Write a function to retrieve the value of the first H1 element from a given Url.

H1 that contains attributes
H1 that contains nested tags
No H1 found in the HTML

Comment: Use jQuery to request it from YQL, and your future imployer will be thoroughly impressed

Comment: I'm working on a script for you, one moment :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Html agility pack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/. You can then use linq to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

So I searched it up online and I found a script and modified it.
I took the file_get_contents function from a project on GitHub.

I hope it will work, tell me, if it's not I will try to fix it.

get.js (var H1 is the first title):

```
function file_get_contents(url, flags, context, offset, maxLen) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/file_get_contents/
  // original by: Legaev Andrey
  //    input by: Jani Hartikainen
  //    input by: Raphael (Ao) RUDLER
  // improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //        note: This function uses XmlHttpRequest and cannot retrieve resource from different domain without modifications.
  //        note: Synchronous by default (as in PHP) so may lock up browser. Can
  //        note: get async by setting a custom "phpjs.async" property to true and "notification" for an
  //        note: optional callback (both as context params, with responseText, and other JS-specific
  //        note: request properties available via 'this'). Note that file_get_contents() will not return the text
  //        note: in such a case (use this.responseText within the callback). Or, consider using
  //        note: jQuery's: $('#divId').load('http://url') instead.
  //        note: The context argument is only implemented for http, and only partially (see below for
  //        note: "Presently unimplemented HTTP context options"); also the arguments passed to
  //        note: notification are incomplete
  //        test: skip
  //   example 1: var buf file_get_contents('http://google.com');
  //   example 1: buf.indexOf('Google') !== -1
  //   returns 1: true

  var tmp, headers = [],
    newTmp = [],
    k = 0,
    i = 0,
    href = '',
    pathPos = -1,
    flagNames = 0,
    content = null,
    http_stream = false;
  var func = function(value) {
    return value.substring(1) !== '';
  };

  // BEGIN REDUNDANT
  this.php_js = this.php_js || {};
  this.php_js.ini = this.php_js.ini || {};
  // END REDUNDANT
  var ini = this.php_js.ini;
  context = context || this.php_js.default_streams_context || null;

  if (!flags) {
    flags = 0;
  }
  var OPTS = {
    FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH: 1,
    FILE_TEXT: 32,
    FILE_BINARY: 64
  };
  if (typeof flags === 'number') { // Allow for a single string or an array of string flags
    flagNames = flags;
  } else {
    flags = [].concat(flags);
    for (i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
      if (OPTS[flags[i]]) {
        flagNames = flagNames | OPTS[flags[i]];
      }
    }
  }

  if (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_BINARY && (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_TEXT)) { // These flags shouldn't be together
    throw 'You cannot pass both FILE_BINARY and FILE_TEXT to file_get_contents()';
  }

  if ((flagNames & OPTS.FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) && ini.include_path && ini.include_path.local_value) {
    var slash = ini.include_path.local_value.indexOf('/') !== -1 ? '/' : '\\';
    url = ini.include_path.local_value + slash + url;
  } else if (!/^(https?|file):/.test(url)) { // Allow references within or below the same directory (should fix to allow other relative references or root reference; could make dependent on parse_url())
    href = this.window.location.href;
    pathPos = url.indexOf('/') === 0 ? href.indexOf('/', 8) - 1 : href.lastIndexOf('/');
    url = href.slice(0, pathPos + 1) + url;
  }

  var http_options;
  if (context) {
    http_options = context.stream_options && context.stream_options.http;
    http_stream = !! http_options;
  }

  if (!context || http_stream) {
    var req = this.window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (!req) {
      throw new Error('XMLHttpRequest not supported');
    }

    var method = http_stream ? http_options.method : 'GET';
    var async = !! (context && context.stream_params && context.stream_params['phpjs.async']);

    if (ini['phpjs.ajaxBypassCache'] && ini['phpjs.ajaxBypassCache'].local_value) {
      url += (url.match(/\?/) == null ? '?' : '&') + (new Date())
        .getTime(); // Give optional means of forcing bypass of cache
    }

    req.open(method, url, async);
    if (async) {
      var notification = context.stream_params.notification;
      if (typeof notification === 'function') {
        // Fix: make work with req.addEventListener if available: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest
        if (0 && req.addEventListener) { // Unimplemented so don't allow to get here
          /*
          req.addEventListener('progress', updateProgress, false);
          req.addEventListener('load', transferComplete, false);
          req.addEventListener('error', transferFailed, false);
          req.addEventListener('abort', transferCanceled, false);
          */
        } else {
          req.onreadystatechange = function(aEvt) { // aEvt has stopPropagation(), preventDefault(); see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIDOMEvent
            // Other XMLHttpRequest properties: multipart, responseXML, status, statusText, upload, withCredentials
            /*
  PHP Constants:
  STREAM_NOTIFY_RESOLVE   1       A remote address required for this stream has been resolved, or the resolution failed. See severity  for an indication of which happened.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_CONNECT   2     A connection with an external resource has been established.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_AUTH_REQUIRED 3     Additional authorization is required to access the specified resource. Typical issued with severity level of STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_ERR.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_MIME_TYPE_IS  4     The mime-type of resource has been identified, refer to message for a description of the discovered type.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_FILE_SIZE_IS  5     The size of the resource has been discovered.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_REDIRECTED    6     The external resource has redirected the stream to an alternate location. Refer to message .
  STREAM_NOTIFY_PROGRESS  7     Indicates current progress of the stream transfer in bytes_transferred and possibly bytes_max as well.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_COMPLETED 8     There is no more data available on the stream.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_FAILURE   9     A generic error occurred on the stream, consult message and message_code for details.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_AUTH_RESULT   10     Authorization has been completed (with or without success).

  STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_INFO 0     Normal, non-error related, notification.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_WARN 1     Non critical error condition. Processing may continue.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_ERR  2     A critical error occurred. Processing cannot continue.
  */
            var objContext = {
              responseText: req.responseText,
              responseXML: req.responseXML,
              status: req.status,
              statusText: req.statusText,
              readyState: req.readyState,
              evt: aEvt
            }; // properties are not available in PHP, but offered on notification via 'this' for convenience
            // notification args: notification_code, severity, message, message_code, bytes_transferred, bytes_max (all int's except string 'message')
            // Need to add message, etc.
            var bytes_transferred;
            switch (req.readyState) {
              case 0:
                //     UNINITIALIZED     open() has not been called yet.
                notification.call(objContext, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0);
                break;
              case 1:
                //     LOADING     send() has not been called yet.
                notification.call(objContext, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0);
                break;
              case 2:
                //     LOADED     send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
                notification.call(objContext, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0);
                break;
              case 3:
                //     INTERACTIVE     Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
                bytes_transferred = req.responseText.length * 2; // One character is two bytes
                notification.call(objContext, 7, 0, '', 0, bytes_transferred, 0);
                break;
              case 4:
                //     COMPLETED     The operation is complete.
                if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                  bytes_transferred = req.responseText.length * 2; // One character is two bytes
                  notification.call(objContext, 8, 0, '', req.status, bytes_transferred, 0);
                } else if (req.status === 403) { // Fix: These two are finished except for message
                  notification.call(objContext, 10, 2, '', req.status, 0, 0);
                } else { // Errors
                  notification.call(objContext, 9, 2, '', req.status, 0, 0);
                }
                break;
              default:
                throw 'Unrecognized ready state for file_get_contents()';
            }
          };
        }
      }
    }

    if (http_stream) {
      var sendHeaders = http_options.header && http_options.header.split(/\r?\n/);
      var userAgentSent = false;
      for (i = 0; i < sendHeaders.length; i++) {
        var sendHeader = sendHeaders[i];
        var breakPos = sendHeader.search(/:\s*/);
        var sendHeaderName = sendHeader.substring(0, breakPos);
        req.setRequestHeader(sendHeaderName, sendHeader.substring(breakPos + 1));
        if (sendHeaderName === 'User-Agent') {
          userAgentSent = true;
        }
      }
      if (!userAgentSent) {
        var user_agent = http_options.user_agent || (ini.user_agent && ini.user_agent.local_value);
        if (user_agent) {
          req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', user_agent);
        }
      }
      content = http_options.content || null;
      /*
      // Presently unimplemented HTTP context options
      var request_fulluri = http_options.request_fulluri || false; // When set to TRUE, the entire URI will be used when constructing the request. (i.e. GET http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html HTTP/1.0). While this is a non-standard request format, some proxy servers require it.
      var max_redirects = http_options.max_redirects || 20; // The max number of redirects to follow. Value 1 or less means that no redirects are followed.
      var protocol_version = http_options.protocol_version || 1.0; // HTTP protocol version
      var timeout = http_options.timeout || (ini.default_socket_timeout && ini.default_socket_timeout.local_value); // Read timeout in seconds, specified by a float
      var ignore_errors = http_options.ignore_errors || false; // Fetch the content even on failure status codes.
      */
    }

    if (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_TEXT) { // Overrides how encoding is treated (regardless of what is returned from the server)
      var content_type = 'text/html';
      if (http_options && http_options['phpjs.override']) { // Fix: Could allow for non-HTTP as well
        content_type = http_options['phpjs.override']; // We use this, e.g., in gettext-related functions if character set
        //   overridden earlier by bind_textdomain_codeset()
      } else {
        var encoding = (ini['unicode.stream_encoding'] && ini['unicode.stream_encoding'].local_value) ||
          'UTF-8';
        if (http_options && http_options.header && (/^content-type:/im)
          .test(http_options.header)) { // We'll assume a content-type expects its own specified encoding if present
          content_type = http_options.header.match(/^content-type:\s*(.*)$/im)[1]; // We let any header encoding stand
        }
        if (!(/;\s*charset=/)
          .test(content_type)) { // If no encoding
          content_type += '; charset=' + encoding;
        }
      }
      req.overrideMimeType(content_type);
    }
    // Default is FILE_BINARY, but for binary, we apparently deviate from PHP in requiring the flag, since many if not
    //     most people will also want a way to have it be auto-converted into native JavaScript text instead
    else if (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_BINARY) { // Trick at https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest to get binary
      req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
      // Getting an individual byte then requires:
      // responseText.charCodeAt(x) & 0xFF; // throw away high-order byte (f7) where x is 0 to responseText.length-1 (see notes in our substr())
    }

    try {
      if (http_options && http_options['phpjs.sendAsBinary']) { // For content sent in a POST or PUT request (use with file_put_contents()?)
        req.sendAsBinary(content); // In Firefox, only available FF3+
      } else {
        req.send(content);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // catches exception reported in issue #66
      return false;
    }

    tmp = req.getAllResponseHeaders();
    if (tmp) {
      tmp = tmp.split('\n');
      for (k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
        if (func(tmp[k])) {
          newTmp.push(tmp[k]);
        }
      }
      tmp = newTmp;
      for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = tmp[i];
      }
      this.$http_response_header = headers; // see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php
    }

    if (offset || maxLen) {
      if (maxLen) {
        return req.responseText.substr(offset || 0, maxLen);
      }
      return req.responseText.substr(offset);
    }
    return req.responseText;
  }
  return false;
}

var filecontent = file_get_contents("www.example.com");

var H1 = $( "h1" ).first().val();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you would do it on the client side using jquery you could do it like this

```
$('#mydiv').load("http://localhost/mypage.html");

var firstH1 = $('#mydiv').children('h1:first-child');

console.log(firstH1);
```